# Fallback mechanism if the case trigger stops email-to-case cases from being created

Tags: email2case

**Problem:**

Email-to-case is configured and cases are also getting created. Let's say someone has built a new validation rule and it stopped creating new cases from email-to-case.

Now once we know that cases are not getting created then we can correct the validation rule. But because of that validation there could be many cases which were supposed to be created but failed.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way to reprocess such emails?
2. Is there any way we could get those emails which did not create cases because of validation rule?
3. Is there any way to get notification if trigger/validation rule prevents cases from being created in email-to-case.

Note: I took validation rule just as an example, problems which could prevent cases from getting created could be trigger/validation/storage limit.

Comment: of course, one could argue that you should have a regression test that validates E2C so this use case doesn't make it to PROD

Comment: @cropredy are you talking about apex unit test. If yes, can we write test class to test the email-to-case functionality. Is it possible to simulate inbound email in apex unit test?